# Does Ezstream can send the incoming microphone audio?

Tags: streaming, microphone, icecast

I'm trying to connect Ezstream to the Icecast server, but i just have found information about sending a mp3 playlist. I wanna send the incoming audio from the microphone.

How should i do it if i wanna send this audio via Ezstream to Icecast?

I know there it's anothers clients for Icecast (i'm already doing this with edcast), but i wanna try another option.

Best regards.

Juan Riquelme.

Comment: What trouble did you have with Edcast?  In my opinion, Edcast is the way to go.

Comment: Sometimes the streaming just stop when i'm using Edcast, anyway i've some "patch solutions" for this issue, like kill the Edcast process each x time, then after that it reconnect to Icecast without any problem. That's the reason why i need to try another solution.

I must say that this solution it's sending the streaming via an satellite internet access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys.

I found that Edcast was the best option for my need. With some troubles of continuity the online streaming, but I fix it forcing the reconnection of edcast by killing the process and using the automatic connection of edcast.

Answer (score 1):

EzStream is only used to play playlists. You need to install DarkIce or Ices to do that...

DarkIce (recommended): [darkice.org](http://www.darkice.org).
Ices: [icecast.org/ices.php](http://www.icecast.org/ices.php).

Comment: ezstream can stream standard input too.